# ReCaptcha not working on Contact page

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.3.x, form

So I have a Joomla! 3.3.6 site and I have everything set up as it's suposed to be (the ReCaptcha as the Global Captcha and I've changed the keys several times, but nothing happens). I use a plug-in, ChronoForms V5 for a registration form in other part of the site and there the ReCaptcha works, but if I use the standard Contact module it doesn't load anything.

You can check it out here: http://uecsants.org/nova_web/entitat/contacta
It's supposed to be over the "Envia Correu" Button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Joomla StackExchange. It looks like you solved the problem. Please consider adding your solution as an answer, it might be useful for other users.